# Custom Quick Action of type 'Send Email' is not shown on a case record

Tags: case, action, casefeed

I have created a Custom Quick Action of type 'Send Email' on Case object. (See attached image below).

[image: Image #1]

I have put it on the Case layout and somehow I don't see it on the Case record. Only the standard email button is shown. (See attached image below).

[image: Image #3]

Moreover, there is no problem to add custom actions of other types like 'Create a Record' etc..
The problem is only with the type of 'Send Email'.

Could anyone please advise?
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Case emails don't use the Messaging Namespace and the [Base Email Class methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_base) like the the actions you're trying to use.  is a different kind of email than regular email services. Case related emails use the ConnectApi and more specifically the [ConnectApi Output Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output.htm). Prior to API 32, cases used the [ConnectApi.EmailMessage Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_emailMessage.htm). In API 32 and later, they've used the [ConnectApi.​EmailMessage​Capability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_email_message_capability.htm). I believe this to be because Case actually has an [email object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm#topic-title) for email to case on which DML is performed which you can learn more about in the Object Reference.

If your intent is to send case related emails, from the case object, that's likely the source of your problem as Email to Case uses a different email messaging method than messaging from other objects to support the Case Feed.